# I want to send message with embed at ban command (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

at 4. and 5. lines i need help.it doesn't send embed.

````
@Bot.command()
@has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member=None, reason=None):
    if member == None or member == ctx.message.author:
        embed1 = discord.Embed(title="ERROR:", description="You can not ban yourself.", color=0x00ff00)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
        return
    if reason == None: 
        reason = 'Nothing.'
    await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=reason)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{ctx.message.author} banned {member} from server. Reason:{reason}")```
````

Comment: replace `discord.User` with `discord.Member`?

Comment: are there any errors printed? (if not: do you have an error handler that blocks it? -> comment it out and try again)

Comment: @Guddi it doesnt print any error.i have missing permission error handler.i disable it and try again but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=reason)
```

Expects a user to ban, not a member.
Try

```
await member.ban(reason=reason)
```

like documented [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.ban).

---

```py
@Bot.command()
@has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member=None, reason=None):
    if member == None or member == ctx.message.author:
        embed1 = discord.Embed(title="ERROR:", description="You can not ban yourself.", color=0x00ff00)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
        return
    if reason == None: 
        reason = 'Nothing.'
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{ctx.message.author} banned {member} from server. Reason:{reason}")
```